# Mass of a half disc

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

A half disc of radius $R$ centered at the origin $(0,0)$, with $y>0$ and density $$\rho = \frac{\rho_oy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\qquad \mbox{for}\, y>0$$ where $\rho_o$ is a constant with units of $\mbox{kg.m}^{-3}$. Determine its mass.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: working on converting the double integrals into polar coordinates with the correct limits of integration as this is the major part.

Comment: The $y$ on the top is going to be a nuisance in polar coordinates. Note that $y=1/2d(y^2)/dy$ so this is perfect for a change of variables.

Comment: The question has been solved by Suzu Hirose using integration by substitution. I have also solved this question myself using polar coordinates and have obtained the exact same answer. There is nothing more to add to this question. Thank you...Bob..........

Comment: Bob actually answered queries in the comments, closing this seems unfair.

Comment: Question has been solved. Question is clearly written and Suzu Hirose answered it perfectly fine. Thank you Bob...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One doesn't need polar coordinates. Let the mass be $m$ then
$$
m=\rho_0\int_{-R}^R\int_{0}^{y_0}{y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dy\, dx
$$
where $y_0=\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$. Substitute $u=y^2$ then $du/2y=dy$ so
$$
\int{y\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dy={1\over2}\int (x^2+u)^{-1/2}du=(x^2+u)^{1/2}+C
$$
where $C$ is a constant of integration. The $x^2$ terms all cancel out:
$$
(x^2+u)^{1/2}|_{0}^{y_0}=R-x
$$
$$
m/\rho_0=\int_0^R(R-x)dx=\frac12R^2.
$$

Comment: yes you are right however I did it in polar coordinates and have obtained the same answer as yours. Thank you.......

Answer (score 0):

Mass would be, 
$$ \iint_D \rho_0 \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $$
Where $D$ is the region you just describe. In polar coordinates we can express $D$ as $0 \leq r \leq 1$ and $0\leq \theta \leq \pi$. Now evaluate through polar coordinates.

Comment: Radius is given as R and not 1. Need to determine the limits of integration when converting to polar coordinates. Then integrate the expression to find M (mass)....